# c++ conversion from 'float' to 'int32', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

build this code return `conversion from 'float' to 'int32', possible loss of data`

how i can solve it and i begging learn cpp

```
uint16 nRandom = Radius;
        if (nRandom <= 0)
            fRandom_X = (float)fX;
        else
            fRandom_X = (float)(myrand((fX - nRandom) * 10, (fX + nRandom) * 10) / 10);

        nRandom = Radius;
        if (nRandom <= 0)
            fRandom_Z = (float)fZ;
        else
            fRandom_Z = (float)(myrand((fZ - nRandom) * 10, (fZ + nRandom) * 10) / 10);

        pNpc->SetPosition(fRandom_X, 0.0f, fRandom_Z);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: ti's give me error while i build project `conversion from 'float' to 'int32', possible loss of data` i just need solve it

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: By using the random header, you can generate integer type random numbers and avoid the conversion issue.

Comment: Where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

(Restricting this answer to IEEE754.)

A `float` cannot store every possible value that an `int32` can (the converse is also true) so your compiler is issuing a helpful warning to you.

A rule of thumb is to not mix your types like this: work with one type and stick to it.

If you need to dive in to floating point then, for an easy life (and possibly faster code these days), use a `double` rather than a `float`. A `double` can store every value that an `int32` can so the warning will go away.

Comment: Why would using `double` help ?  The compiler warns about conversion from `float` to `int`, not `int` to `float`.